# Why I can't post to public groups on facebook via graph API? (#200) The user has not authorized

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-group

I can't post on my own groups, even I have publish_actions and user_managed_groups permissions. I posted for years now, but suddenly I can't for no reason and no alterations to my code.
Since 21 March I receive "(#200) The user has not authorized the application to perform this action."

Comment: File a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I don't think it is a bug, maybe admins of the apps are not allowed anymore to post without some new permission? Or publish_actions now have to be reviewed by facebook before granted? When I request only this permission there is a popup telling that.

Comment: It seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been confirmed. Please follow this link https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1655744048061679/.